# Ubuntu Server 20.04 2TB server out of space after 200GB space used

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, ssd

Yesterday my server provider provide me a 2TB SSD Ubuntu 20.04 server. But After sync with AWS S3 bucket around after used 185 GB space my server showing out of Space. I am novice in managing Server Space. I stored all file in `/srv` folder. What should I do? How I can I use remaining space? Please help

Here my SSD information:

```
sudo lshw -C disk
  *-disk                    
       description: ATA Disk
       product: CT2000MX500SSD1
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: 022
       serial: 1831E14C2802
       size: 1863GiB (2TB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=a12f8a10-eab0-4417-9736-447f958bd104 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
```

Here the df information

```
df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              1.5G  1.3M  1.5G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  196G  185G  1.4G 100% /
tmpfs                              7.5G     0  7.5G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  113M  796M  13% /boot
tmpfs                              1.5G  4.0K  1.5G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Another Information:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME                      FSTYPE       SIZE MOUNTPOINT        LABEL
loop0                     squashfs    55.3M /snap/core18/1885 
loop1                     squashfs    69.2M /snap/lxd/17936   
loop2                     squashfs    30.9M /snap/snapd/9721  
loop3                     squashfs    32.3M /snap/snapd/13170 
loop4                     squashfs    61.8M /snap/core20/1081 
loop5                     squashfs    55.4M /snap/core18/2128 
loop6                     squashfs    72.5M /snap/lxd/21497   
sda                                    1.8T                   
├─sda1                                   1M                   
├─sda2                    ext4           1G /boot             
└─sda3                    LVM2_member  1.8T                   
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4         200G /
```

Comment: Please try and reword the question I can make no sense of it and I think it needs more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using LVM and your logical volume is only 200GB.  You can extend your logical volume with the following:

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

You do not need to unmount to extend it.  After that, extend the volume group with:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

You can view status with these commands

```
pvs (view physical volumes)
vgs (view volume groups)
lvs (view logical volumes)
```

Another option would be to create more volumes and mount points using LVM, then move the data over to the new mount point.  For instance make a `/var` volume and move the data from your /var to it, clean up the old and mount the new.

Comment: Thanks. It worked I extended the remaining space instead of creating.